# SSRS report grouping by row count

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Good afternoon.
I'm working on rebuilding some of our old ssrs reports. i have a report that uses cursors and builds a temp table i want to get away from.
[image: what the report looks like now.]
basically each row has 43 items and then it puts item "44+" into the next column group over and repeats. there is never move than 105 items on this single report.
I have attempted to use a matrix with a column grouping of "=CEILING(RowNumber(Nothing) / 43)"  and "=(RowNumber(Nothing) - 1) Mod 3" something i have attempted to piece together over a morning of googling.
[image: i get a result like this]
any help would greatly be appreciated.
[image: here is some example data that i am using]

Comment: The simple answer is to add the `ROW_NUMBER()` into the query then you can use that as a value reference in your grouping expression. Post your query and we can help.

Comment: and if you can script out your sample data, testing it will be easier for us.